# How to Check the number of lines in a String in Android?

Tags: android, view, textview

I want to check the no of lines in my text view from the string I am going to pass to the test view. I have added android:maxLines = "2".... If it exceeds two i need to show/hide a view....How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can check it only if your TextView contains `\n` otherwise I dont think it is possible.

Comment: Also, I think the android:maxLines property will **coerce** the number of lines to 2, so I don't think it will be possible to exceed.  Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: use @android:ellipsize = "end"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a thread to count the number of lines,

```
 textView.setText("Text Here");
    textView.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Log.v("Line count: ", textView.getLineCount()+"");
        }
    });
```

If you want to limit the number of lines in TextView from xml then use `android:maxLines`

Comment: What if it returns the exact number of lines as the max number? In this case, it can either be enough or not...

Answer (score 3):

I believe the TextView has a method getLineCount which you can use to get the number of lines.  You can compare that function's return value with maxLines and show/hide if the limit is reached.

See also: [TextView.getLine()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getLineCount())

And: [TextView - maxLines attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLines)