# What's the difference between view.post() and GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main)?

Tags: android, multithreading

Actually I met a problem with dynamically adjusting the textview gravity which depends on its line count.

I read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22854554/how-to-check-the-number-of-lines-in-a-string-in-android), but I just don't really understand the difference about threading techniques, just like `textview.post()`, `runOnUiThread{}`, `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main)`, `Thead{}.start()`.

TLDR, short question is "***Why the codes below should be run in the `post` scope?***"

```
private fun setText(text : String) {
    textView.text = text

    textView.post {
        if (textView.lineCount > 1) {
            textView.gravity = Gravity.START
        }else {
            textView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        }
    }
}
```

and another short question is "***Why it doesn't work in the GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main)?***"

This is my try:

```
private fun setText(text : String) {
    textView.text = text

    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        if (textView.lineCount > 1) {
            textView.gravity = Gravity.START
        }else {
            textView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to put it into GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main), but it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't work.
Also, I tried to make it without `textView.post()`, and it just doesn't work.
The source code of `getLineCount()` doesn't seem to be async operation?

Any suggestion is welcome, thanks for everything.

Comment: Read about post() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840007/what-exactly-does-the-post-method-do

Comment: @AshokKumar Thanks for your reply, I've read related articles about `post()` and `runOnUiThread`, and knowing that `post` will be enqueued to run, `runOnUiThread` will run directly.
Can you please explain why these code must be in the `post()` scope?
```
if (textView.lineCount > 1) {
    textView.gravity = Gravity.START
}else {
    textView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Difference between view.post() and GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main)?

The "post" methods (`View.post(...)`, `View.postDelayed(...)`, etc.) put the `Runnable` to queue which is processed by UI/Main thread. The point here is to do all UI updates from a single thread.

What `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main)` does is that (in addition to aforementioned *post* methods) it allows you to use all the features provided by [Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html): for example you can `suspend` the code execution without blocking the Main/UI thread. That means that you can code in imperative style which comes handy for more complicated scenarios, like [updating UI in loop each few milliseconds](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md#:%7E:text=update%20anything%20in%20UI%20and%20suspend%20without%20blocking%20the%20main%20thread). You just `suspend` the loop for as long as you need. With *post* methods you would have to call `View.post(...)` with new `Runnable` every few ms to update the UI. For more details read the whole [Guide to UI programming with coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md).

#### 2. "... it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't ..."

I believe, that the reason why your implementation "sometimes works and sometimes doesn't" might be, that you need to call all UI manipulation methods from within the UI (aka Main) thread; meaning that your `textView.text = text` should also be part of your post block.

```
private fun setText(text : String) {
    textView.post {
        textView.text = text
        if (textView.lineCount > 1) {
            textView.gravity = Gravity.START
        }else {
            textView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        }
    }
}
```